# Hibernate saveAndUpdate doesnt persist relations, while merge does

Tags: hibernate

I have the following entity with the following relation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bpr_user")
public abstract class User {
  ...
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH,  CascadeType.REMOVE})
   @JoinColumn(name = "bcard_id", nullable = true)
   public BCard getBcard() {
     return bcard;
   }
}
```

When I run merge like this:

```
    Adult adult = new Adult();
    BCard bcard = createBCard();
    adult.setBcard(bcard);
    adult = adultDao.merge(adult);
```

The Bcard entity get persisted and given an id, but if I use saveOrUpdate only Adult get persisted, not Bcard. Why??

```
    Adult adult = new Adult();
    BCard bcard = createBCard();
    adult.setBcard(bcard);
    adult = adultDao.saveOrUpdate(adult);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have configured a cascade for MERGE, but not for SAVE_UPDATE.

Use the [Cascade annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Cascade.html) to add a cascade for SAVE_UPDATE.